# Unable to install Intel compiler

Tags: intel, compiler

```
Cannot install Intel(R) Cluster Toolkit Compiler Edition for Linux* OS version 3.2.2p-013 to "/home/intel/ictce/3.2.2.013":
This prefix directory path '/home/intel/ictce/3.2.2.013' is owned by cookie intel-ictce_em64t version 3.2.2p-013.
Completed cluster installation with errors in the following components:
  Intel(R) MPI Benchmarks on current node.
  Intel(R) Trace Analyzer and Collector for Linux* OS on current node.
  Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS on current node.
  Intel(R) Cluster Toolkit documentation on current node.
emphasized text
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: What does the installation manual say about the ownership of '/home/intel/ictce/3.2.2.013' ?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @Soren A -  I dont have installation manual.

Comment: @moghees ... Are you sure that there aren't an installation manual or guide on the homepage from where you downloaded the package ?

Comment: @Soren A -- My friend who gave it to me didn't have any installation manual.

Comment: @moghees  I have no idea on how to help you then, when I search on Google I only find documentation for Ubuntu 9.10 and 12-04 or so. This is very old shit. Maybe you can ask your or find a relevant Intel forum ?